# Why doesn't my superuser account show up on the network-wide accounts list?

Tags: support, user-accounts, stackexchange

I am using the same Google account to register for [Super User](https://superuser.com/users/94585/joe-m?tab=accounts) as I did for Stack Overflow, Server Fault, and IT security, but my  [Super User account](https://superuser.com/users/94585/joe-m?tab=accounts) doesn't show up on my network-wide profile accounts list. Below is the link to my accounts list, not sure if it is accessible to other users or not:

- http://stackexchange.com/users/d1f66e33-b0de-4738-b7e0-9df286869785?tab=accounts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You registered on Super User about <s>10 minutes</s> 14 hours ago. I suspect the linked page is heavily cached, give it some more time(a day or two) to sync the new account.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I registered some time yesterday. I think maybe you are looking at when I registered on super user meta?

Comment: it does only show "member for today" on your SU profile, though I've had it take a few days to show a new account on the network profile page.

Comment: @JoeM. I was pretty sure I was looking at your main site profile http://i.imgur.com/fGFhm.png edited based on the time

Comment: Interesting.. sorry if I sounded argumentative about it.. I am pretty certain that I associated the google account yesterday. And I did just sign up on meta before your initial response. Maybe it waited until I took a certain action on the site? I'll be patient with it. Thanks again!

Comment: Funny thing.. I *just now* joined the stack overflow meta, and that is already showing up on the list, but still no superuser: http://stackexchange.com/users/d1f66e33-b0de-4738-b7e0-9df286869785?tab=accounts

Comment: @JoeM. No need to apologize, "today" is a relative term when you've people from different timezones :) what's today for you is yesterday for me ;)

Comment: For the record, I just checked a few minutes ago and it still wasn't showing. Finally got fed up and clicked the "clear all stack exchange account associations" button. The list cleared out completely. A few minutes later it was repopulated with all the correct sites including superuser.